# Insert XElement in XCData

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, xelement

I'm modifying an XML generator script that pulls data from a Sharepoint list, and generates XML from it.

One section of the XML looks like:

```
<node>
    <node2>
        <![CDATA[
            <p>Some text</p>
        ]]>
    </node2>
    <otherNodesHere>Yadda yadda</otherNodesHere>
</node>
```

The data being pulled from a data list is going to be "Some text" without the surrounding P tags.

So, what I'm *wanting* to do is (snippet):

```
new XElement("node",
    new XElement("node2",
        new XCData(
            new XElement("p", variableForTheDatainSP)),
```

But I can't do new XCData(new XElement("p", ....)),
What would be a simple way to go about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `<p>Some text</p>` isn't *really* an `XElement` - it's just text that looks like XML. So you'd use:

```
new XElement("node",
    new XElement("node2",
        new XCData("<p>Some text</p>")))
```

Or if you wanted to build it *via* an `XElement`, you could always call `ToString()`:

```
new XElement("node",
    new XElement("node2",
        new XCData(
            new XElement("p", variableForTheDatainSP).ToString()),
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not an element.
The whole point of `CDATA` blocks is that they can *only* hold plain text.

If you want to put plain text that looks like XML into the `CDATA` block, you can pass `new XElement(...).ToString()` to get the raw XML string.

Comment: I do get that, about the CDATA. Unfortunately, the look of the XML is out of my hands. I was merely given an XML Document to go from, and have to add to the XML generator script to make sure it spits out identical XML with the data pulled from our lists.